# Area of Triangle, Sine

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, area, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

In any triangle $ABC$, $a$ and $b$ are the sides of the triangle. Given that $S=\dfrac12ab\sin C$ (where $S$ is the area of the triangle), then

A) $S \geq \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{4}$

B) $S \leq \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{4}$

C) $S \geq \dfrac{a^2+b^2-ab}{2}$

D) $S \leq \dfrac{a^2+b^2-ab}{2}$

E) None of these

Which of the above options is true?

Using AM-GM inequality I got the option (B) as an answer. But it seems option (D) is also valid. But according to the original question, only one of the options is correct.

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM $$S=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\gamma\leq\frac{1}{2}ab\leq\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}\leq\frac{a^2+b^2-ab}{2},$$
where the last inequality it's $(a-b)^2\geq0.$

Id est, B) and D) they are valid.